# C++ No member named

Tags: c++, class, methods, winpcap

So i have this "example" code

## Packets.h

```
#ifndef PACKETS_H_
#define PACKETS_H_

#include <winsock2.h>

typedef unsigned char u_char;
typedef unsigned short u_short;
typedef unsigned int u_int;

/* Some code here */

typedef struct _UDP
{
    u_short UDP_Source_Port;
    u_short UDP_Destination_Port;
    u_short UDP_Total_Length;
    u_short UDP_CheckSum;
} _UDP;

class _Packet
{
    private:
        _IPv4_Header* IPv4_Header;
        _UDP* UDP;
        _TCP* TCP;
    public:
        _Packet(void);
        ~_Packet(void);
        void Analyze(const u_char* Packet_Data);

            /* Some code here */

        u_short Get_UDP_Source_Port(void) { return UDP->UDP_Destination_Port; }
        u_short Get_UDP_Destination_Port(void) { return UDP->UDP_Destination_Port; }
        u_short Get_UDP_Total_Length(void) { return UDP->UDP_Total_Length; }
        u_short Get_UDP_CheckSum(void) { return UDP->UDP_CheckSum; }
};

#endif
```

## Packets.cpp

```
#include "Packets.h"
#include <pcap.h>

_Packet::_Packet(void)
{

}

_Packet::~_Packet(void)
{

}

void _Packet::Analyze(const u_char* Packet_Data)
{
    IPv4_Header = (_IPv4_Header*) Packet_Data;
    if (0x06 == Get_IPv4_Protocol())
        TCP = (_TCP*) Packet_Data + (int)Get_IPv4_Header_Length() / 4;
    else if (0x11 == Get_IPv4_Protocol())
        UDP = (_UDP*) Packet_Data + (int)Get_IPv4_Header_Length() / 4;
}

/* Some code here */
```

packets.cpp: In member function 'void _Packet::Analyze(const u_char*)':

packets.cpp:20:3: error: 'UDP' was not declared in this scope

packets.cpp:20:10: error: '_UDP' was not declared in this scope

packets.cpp:20:15: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token

packets.cpp:20:17: error: expected ';' before 'Packet_Data'

## main.cpp

```
/* Some code here */

_Packet Packet;
cout << "  Source port: " << Packet.Get_UDP_Source_Port() << endl;
cout << "  Destination port: " << Packet.Get_UDP_Destination_Port() << endl;

/* Some code here */
```

main.cpp:126:40: error: 'class _Packet' has no member named 'Get_UDP_Source_Port'

main.cpp:127:45: error: 'class _Packet' has no member named 'Get_UDP_Destination_Port

I don't know why this error appears. It should work properly

Comment: Well identifiers beginning with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for the implementation, so you have undefined behaviour.

Comment: In C++ you don't need to use `typedef` for a structure or class. The structure name is a proper type.

Comment: OK, I did everything according to Your instructions and it works. Thanks!